# PHP can't add to db with form on page with id in url and go back to page with id in url

Tags: php, sql, url, sql-insert

Situation: I have a page called 'lid.php'. You get here from the home page after clicking a link and the url gets a unique Id like -> 'lid.php?lidnummer=4'. this page shows all data from a member in my database with the ID of 4.

On this page there are 2 forms to add a phone number or email to said member. After submitting one of the forms it (should) goes to a page called 'create.php' which query's the data to the database but this doesn't work. Also, after it not working it should go back to the same 'lid.php?lidnummer=x' page but that also doesn't work.

The db table consists of just a phone number (PK) and the member id (FK)

I am still learning... so please answer with a good explanation what I am doing wrong and how I should solve this issue. (also..sorry if I framed my question a bit poorly because I didn't know a proper way to ask)

[EDIT] added code that shows a single member on screen

**form for contact details**

```
    <form action="includes/create.php" method="POST"><b>
        <label for="telefoonnummer">
            Telefoonnummer:
            <input type="text" name="telefoonnummer">
        </label>
        <button type="submit" name='add_telnr'>Voeg telnr toe</button>
    </form><br>

    <form action="includes/create.php" method="POST">        
        <label for="email">
            Email:
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </label>
        <button type="submit" name='add_email'>Voeg email toe</button></b>
    </form><br>
</div>
```

Code that handles adding phone number

```
if(isset($_POST['add_telnr'])) {
    $telnr = get_post($conn, 'telefoonnummer');
    $lidnummer = $_GET['lidnummer'];

    $stmt_telnr = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO telefoonnummers VALUES(?,?)");
    $stmt_telnr->bind_param('si', $telnr, $lidnummer);
    $stmt_telnr->execute();

    if($stmt_telnr->affected_rows != 1) { 
        echo '<script> alert("Telefoonnummer niet toegevoegd. Waarschijnlijk bestaat deze al. Controleer de lijst en/of probeer het opnieuw.") </script>';
        echo '<script> window.location.href = "../lid.php?lidnummer=' . $lidnummer . '" </script>';         
    } else {
        header("location: ../lid.php?lidnummer=' . $lidnummer . '");
    }
    $stmt_telnr->close();
}
```

Code that shows member on screen

```
if(isset($_GET['lidnummer'])) { 
    $lidnummer = $_GET['lidnummer']; 

    $select_lid_query = "SELECT * FROM leden 
                            JOIN postcodes
                            WHERE lidnummer='$lidnummer'";

    $select_lid_result = $conn->query($select_lid_query);
    if(!$select_lid_query) die ("<span style='color:red'>" . "Kon geen gegevens van de database ophalen. 
                                Klik a.u.b. op het pijltje terug in de browser en probeert u het opnieuw" . "</span>");

    $gegevens_lid = $select_lid_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    foreach($gegevens_lid as $data => $info) {
        if($data == 'lidnummer' || $data == 'adres' || $data == 'woonplaats') {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><b>' . ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($data)) . '</b></td>';
            echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($info) . '</td>';
            echo '<td> ---- </td>';
            echo '<td> ---- </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        } else {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><b>' . ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($data)) . '</b></td>';
            echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($info) . '</td>';
            echo '<td> update </td>';
            echo '<td> ---- </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }

    toon_contactgegevens('telefoonnummers', $gegevens_lid, $conn, 'telefoonnummer', 'lid_table');
    toon_contactgegevens('emails', $gegevens_lid, $conn, 'email', 'lid_table');

    $select_lid_result->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: When you POST from a form you are not sending the `lidnummer` on the querystring, so `$lidnummer = $_GET['lidnummer'];` will not work, $_GET will be empty. I personally woudl put the `lidnummer` in a hidden field on the form so it also gets transmitted when you submit the form, but then it will be in the `$_POST` array

Comment: @RiggsFolly how to I extract the 'lidnummer' from the url once I am on the page already?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `lidnummer` around to all the scripts.  In `create.php` you call `$_GET['lidnummer']` but it isn't available, because you didn't pass it into that script.

In your form you need something like this right before the button:

```php
<input type=hidden name=lidnummer value="<?php echo $lidnummer ?>">
```